# How to check emptiness and null for all fields in a Class and implement user-defined exception?

Tags: java, exception

Customer Class:

```
public class Customer {
 String name;
 String password;
 String Address;
 int age;
//and getter setter of the above fields
```

}

In Main method:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setName(null);
customer.setAge(25);
customer.setAddress("Address");
```

In the main method **name** field sets with null, and **password** is NOT even set a value. In this case, if no values set needs to throw user defined Exception.

UPDATE #1:
if suppose out of 100 fields in a Customer class, any one of the field has null or empty then need to throw InadequateResourceException. How can I proceed with?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `if (name == null) throw new InadequateResourceException();` It's really that simple.

Comment: Create a custome exception like `customException extends Exception`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class has a no-argument constructor and setters, you need to check it for validity. You could introduce a method

```
boolean valid()
```

that returns `true` if the instance has all tha it needs.

Answer (score 1):

Define your own custom exception and throw that.

*How to implement custom exception?* you can try something similar to following.

```
public class MyException extends Exception{

 public MyException() {
    super();
 }

 public MyException(Exception e) {
    super(e);
 }

 public MyException(String message, Exception e) {
    super(message, e);
 }

 public MyException(String message) {
    super(message);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee all Customers have their necessary values assigned, define a single Constructor that clearly states the obligatory fields:

```
public Customer(String name, String password)
{
   this.name = name;
   this.password = password;
}
```

You can also test the parameters for nullness, emptiness, etc. and throw a [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) if needed.